# why is this palindrome code in C not working?

Tags: c

it's a very simple code but it's not working for some reason, always says that the number is not a palindrome even if it is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
   int n, rev = 0, rem;
   printf ("enter number: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   while (n!=0){

   rem = n % 10;

   rev = rev * 10 + rem;

   n = n / 10;
   }

   if ( rev == n) {
      printf("Number is a palindrome");}

   else{
      printf("Number is not a palindrome");}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" could help.

Comment: You would get a clue about the nature of the problem by printing the values of `n` and `rev` at the end of your program.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that after the `while (n!=0)` loop , the value of variable called **n** will always be zero as you are always doing this line  `n = n / 10;` until **n** becomes zero , and after the while loop , you are checking if `if ( rev == n)` and this is wrong as **n** is always zero.

so what I did is to add a dummy variable called `original_n` to keep the original value of **n** and instead of `if ( rev == n)` , I did `if ( rev == original_n)`

and the edited code is :

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n, rev = 0, rem;
    int original_n;
    printf ("enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    original_n = n;

    while (n!=0){

        rem = n % 10;

        rev = rev * 10 + rem;

        n = n / 10;
    }

    if ( rev == original_n) {
        printf("Number is a palindrome");}

    else{
        printf("Number is not a palindrome");}

    return 0;
}
```

and here is output example :

```
enter number:222
Number is a palindrome

enter number:1234
Number is not a palindrome
```